# Am I in the Top 10 users of my country?

Tags: discussion, reputation, users, top-users

I found this [top Users by Country](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/53058/top-users-by-country), but when I query for Greece, I do not even see me in the results. Am I missing something?

Note: I was living in San Francisco, USA. I changed that to Athens, Greece, before I executed the query. But maybe the update is not yet reflected in the server or something.

Comment: The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was Jun 24 at 7:54. [From faq](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq)

Comment: You can also confirm your location by querying for your user row—[you can see your location is still San Francisco](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/867642/top-users-by-country) as of now.

Comment: Ah yes, I should have thought that @Aurora0001, nice!

Comment: Now it's updated, you're tenth rank :-)

Comment: Indeed @U9-Forward! :D

Comment: @gsamaras Lol, yes, no question :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a SEDE query. SEDE data is not updated instantaneously. You will need to wait.

From their [help](https://data.stackexchange.com/help):

> *How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?*
>
> The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was Jun 24 at 7:54.